# How to get libspatialite.so file for spatialite

Tags: spatialite, php

I am creating an application using spatialite database. I checked couple of tutorial from internet. Most of them explains the same. But the problem is I need "libspatialite.so" extension library. I do not know how to get it.

So whenever i run my code it shows the following warning and error....

```
[Warning: SQLite3::query() [sqlite3.query]: Unable to prepare statement: 1, no such module:]
[Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchArray() on a non-object]
```

But my code looks OK. It looks like because of i could not load the extention "libspatialite.so"

I have given bellow, my code.

```
<?php

$db = new SQLite3('sixcommunes.sqlite'); 

$db->loadExtension('libspatialite.so'); 

$db->exec("SELECT InitSpatialMetadata()");

$rs = $db->query('SELECT sqlite_version()');

while ($row = $rs->fetchArray()) {
    print "<h3>SpatialLite version: $row[0]</h3>";
}

$sql = "SELECT KOM_NAMN FROM '6communes_SWEREF99TM'";

$rs = $db->query($sql);
$msg = "";
while($row = $rs->fetchArray()){
        $msg = $row[0];
    print "<h3>$msg</h3>";
}
$db->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What computer? If Ubuntu/Debian, try:

```
sudo apt-get install libspatialite-dev
```

Comment: My computer is windows 7. It this case what should I do?

Comment: `.so` files are for Unix-like systems. For Windows, you need to find a DLL equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for help. I have the windows dll. I do not know how should I configure my wampserver. Could you please read the following question, if you can help me somehow. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22064/how-to-configure-wampserver-for-spatialite