# How to configure wampserver for spatialite

Tags: spatialite, php

I am in windows 7. I installed WAMPServer. Now, I can not load spatialite libraries. It is showing warning..

> Warning: SQLite3::loadExtension() [sqlite3.loadextension]: Not
>   supported in multithreaded Web servers

Here is my total configuration procedure, what I have done...

From this link I got spatialite lib. I copied "libspatialite-1.dll" and paste it to "D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.8\ext" which contains php extention dlls.

*http://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-2.3.1/libspatialite-win-x86-2.3.1.zip*

Then I edited php.ini file. I changed the following configuration.

```
.
sqlite3.extension_dir = C:\libspatialite-win-x86-2.3.1\bin
.
extension=libspatialite-1.dll
.
enable_dl = On
```

And lastly, I copy and paste all the libraries from my downloaded libspatialite-win-x86-2.3.1 to my project folder(*libspatialite.a, libspatialite.dll.a, libspatialite.la*) in my php code i write the script as follows...

```
<?php

$db = new SQLite3('sixcommunes.sqlite'); 

$db->loadExtension('libspatialite.a'); 

$rs = $db->query('SELECT spatialite_version()');
while($row = $rs->fetchArray()){
    print "<h3>SQLite version: $row[0]</h3>";
}

?>
```

I do not know what I have done wrong or how to solve this problem?

Comment: This is more of an Apache issue than a GIS issue. Have you tried stackoverflow? You might get more luck there.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have already done that, already.

Answer (score 1):

Did you ever get this resolved? If not, try replacing the .a suffix with .dll. You can't load an archive (.a) in place of a shared library (.dll).